# Counting Multiple Column Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table that (among other things) includes 10 different detail and quantity fields:

```
detail_1 | qty_1 | detail_2 | qty_2 | detail_3 | qty_3 | detail_4 | qty_4 | detail_5 | qty_5 | detail_6 | qty_6 |  ...etc
```

I'm trying to add up the quantities of each record and then count the number of records that share a common total.  I've managed to achieve this using the following statement:

```
SELECT a.Total as [Quantity], COUNT(a.Total) as [Total]
FROM

(SELECT (ISNULL(qty_1, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_2, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_3, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_4, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_5, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_6, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_7, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_8, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_9, 0) 
       + ISNULL(qty_10, 0)) as [Total]                  
FROM endicia_temp) a

GROUP BY a.Total
ORDER BY Quantity
```

This gives me my desired output:

```
Quantity Total
2        169    //169 records with total quantity 2
13       2      //2 records with total quantity 13
16       39
17       1
55       2
107      1      //1 record with total quantity 107
```

The problem I'm having now is that I need to add a where clause so that only certain quantities from each record are included in the total.  Something like `WHERE [detail_column_here] LIKE '%sample%'`.  The idea being that the one record may include just `qty_1` (based on detail_1) while another may include `qty_3`, `qty_4`, and `qty_5` (based on `detail_3`, `detail_4`, and `detail_5`).  Maybe I'm over-thinking it but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: @paqogomez Oops, you're right.  The distinct was not needed.  Code updated.

Comment: Well you can filter on the detail columns by adding a WHERE clause to your inner query.  Is that not what you need?

Comment: What do you need that much `detail` and `qty` columns for, tell me? I don't think your data model is clean.

Comment: Add `CASE WHEN ... END` for each quantity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with the table structure you have, the only option is to have a CASE statement in each component of the sum:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN detail_1 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_1, 0) ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_2 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_2, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_3 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_3, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_4 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_4, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_5 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_5, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_6 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_6, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_7 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_7, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_8 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_8, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_9 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_9, 0)  ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN detail_10 LIKE '%sample%' THEN ISNULL(qty_10, 0) ELSE 0 END)
```

As you may already know, normalizing your structure will simplify queries like this significantly.

Comment: Why wouldn't a WHERE clause on the inner query achieve the same results?

Comment: @TabAlleman No because the filter needs to be applied to _each detail column_.  If `detail_1`, `detail_2`, etc. were separate _rows_ then a `WHERE` clause would work.

Comment: Ok, I see, I got a little lost in the renormalization process myself.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks for the speedy response.  Unfortunately I can't normalize the table as it's the source table for some software that we use.  This is a good answer for an ugly situation.  Cheers!